# accessing old database (.db) - possibly ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, database-restore

I have inherited old data which apparently was created with ColdFusion.  I have never used ColdFusion and I simply have a file with the extension .db

Basically I need to access the data (which is simply records of animals in a herd and related information).  I just want to get to the data and pull it off into excel.  I have an idea of what the data will look like since more recent years of data were created in an Access database.

Any ideas on the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything specifically CF-related about a .db file (unless it's an old thing - early versions of CF had .dbm/.dbml extensions, but afaik that was for code not data). **What does the file look like when you open it in either a text editor or a hex viewer?**

Comment: Are you sure it is not a thumb.db that has been renamed?

Comment: A Thumbs.db file is still a database file (using a common Microsoft format). Immensely more likely than being a renamed thumbnail cache is that it was created by another Microsoft product, e.g. MSWorks. But .db is sufficiently generic that it could easily have been any number of other desktop DB systems too (e.g. dBASE, Paradox, etc). To re-iterate, the way to check this is to **look at the file content**. If the first 4 bytes in hex are `d0cf11e0` it is probably an MS format.